# Immediately return a resolved promise using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, restangular, angular-promise

I'm trying to get my head around promises in JavaScript (in particular AngularJS).

I have a function in a service, let's call it `fooService`, that checks if we've loaded some data. If it has, I just want it to return, and if we haven't, we need to load the data and return a promise:

```
this.update = function(data_loaded) {
    if (data_loaded) return;  // We've loaded the data, no need to update

    var promise = Restangular.all('someBase').customGet('foo/bar').then(function(data) {
        // Do something with the data here
    }

    return promise;
}
```

I have another function that then calls the `update` function of `fooService` like so:

```
fooService.update(data_loaded).then(function() {
    // Do something here when update is finished
})
```

My issue here is that if we don't need to load the data in the `update` function, a promise isn't returned, so the `.then()` is not called in my other function. What should the approach be here - basically I want to return a resolved promise immediately from the `update()` function if we do not need to get data from the Restangular call?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The current accepted answer is overly complicated, and abuses the [deferred anti pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-deferred-anti-pattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it). Here is a simpler approach:

```
this.update = function(data_loaded) {
    if (data_loaded) return $q.when(data);  // We've loaded the data, no need to update

    return Restangular.all('someBase').customGet('foo/bar')
                             .then(function(data) {
        // Do something with the data here 
    });
};
```

Or, even further:

```
this._updatep = null;
this.update = function(data_loaded) { // cached
    this._updatep = this._updatep || Restangular.all('someBase') // process in
                                                .customGet('foo/bar'); //.then(..
    return this._updatep;
};
```

Comment: Thanks for a tip. I always missed the `Q(initialVal)` syntax of [Kris Kowal's Q](https://github.com/kriskowal/q) and should have known `$q.when(data)` can do the same trick.

Answer (score 51):

As your promise use the same syntax as the JavaScript native one, you could use and return an  already resolved JavaScript promise : [Promise.resolve()](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Promise/resolve)

```
return(Promise.resolve("MyReturnValue"));
```

Comment: This is the answer I wanted; I have a value; it's ready, I just want to wrap it in a Promise to satisfy APIs which expect Promises... So while the OP asked, "Immediately return a resolved promise", what **I** wanted was to "return a Promise , which I resolved immediately (with a literal)"

Comment: That's what I wanted too. I have an object and just need to return a promise since that's what the API expects.

Comment: Careful for IE support on this answer. $q provides cross browser support

Comment: @JosefE., good point regarding IE support. The ideal answer would address both the modern Javascript case (in a modern browser or using a transpiler) and the legacy case. Let us pray to the Microsoft gods that IE soon becomes obsolete.

Answer (score 6):

AngularJS's [***$q***](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) service will help you here. It is much like [Kris Kowal's Q](https://github.com/kriskowal/q) promise library.

When you have an async method that may return a promise or value use the [***$q.when***](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#when) method. It will take what ever is passed to it, be it a promise or a value and create a promise that will be resolved/rejected based on the promise passed, or resolved if a value is passed.

```
$q.when( fooService.update(data_loaded) ).then(function(data){
   //data will either be the data returned or the data
   //passed through from the promise
})
```

and then in your update function return the data instead of just returning

```
if (data_loaded) return data_loaded;
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to [Elo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31312689), you can return an already resolved promise using the async/await syntax:

```
this.update = async (data_loaded) => {

    if (data_loaded) 
        return await null;  // Instead of null, you could also return something else
                            // like a string "Resolved" or an object { status: 200 }
    else 
        return await OtherPromise();
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You could use the `$q.defer()` like this:

```
this.update = function (data_loaded) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();

    if (data_loaded) {
        deferred.resolve(null); // put something that your callback will know the data is loaded or just put your loaded data here.
    } else {
        Restangular.all('someBase').customGet('foo/bar').then(function(data) {
            // Do something here when update is finished
            deferred.resolve(data);
        }
    }

    return deferred.promise;
};
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have no idea how this got upvoted twice, this is the deferred anti pattern and can be greatly simplified.

Comment: It's not only the deferred antipattern, it also fails to propagate errors.

Comment: @Benjamin IMHO, this is not exactly the same as the deferred anti pattern. The deffered anti pattern you mention is when the deferred can be removed completely without a lose of functionality. But yes, your answer is much simpler and also handle error well.

Comment: @samtuner please accept the Benjamin's answer instead of this.

Comment: @Bergi imo the biggest problem with this solution is the fact it will make multiple requests instead of one if this method is called several times before the data is returned since the data is cached instead of the promise and there is no a "already sent" flag. Error handling is a biggie too though so you're right there.